# UIView that retains data similar to TabBarController XCODE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have built a program without a menu. The main view has custom buttons which loads XIBs depending on which button is pressed. The only issue i'm having is when I go back to an already used view, its reset. I have tried "retain" in viewDidUnload and in viewWillUnload. I have tried everything I can thin of and cant get it to work.

```
- (IBAction)gotoMusicView:(id)sender{
    //[self.view addSubview:musicview];
    if(self.musicMenuData == nil)
    {
        musicMenu *musicview = [[musicMenu alloc]initWithNibName:@"musicMenu" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.musicMenuData = musicview;
        musicview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:musicview animated:YES];
        [musicview release];
    }

    musicMenu *musicview = [[musicMenu alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    musicview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:musicview animated:YES];

   }
```

That musicview loads fine. After I leave that view and go back to the main view, it is RELEASED. Therefore when I reopen "musicview" everything , such as my UIWebView, has reset as if I am opening it again for the 1st time

Comment: By reset, do you mean that the code in viewDidLoad is executing?  Also, please post the code related to showing and creating the controller for the already used view.

Answer (score 1):

Create a singleton class using [this](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons.html)

And then initialize your .xibs there so you can use the same instance everytime you load the .xib. This way it'll never reset

Answer (score 1):

Instead of allocating and initializing each time you need to use it, keep a reference of all the view controllers you're using, check of its nil on the first time if so initialize, example below.

```
if(self.someViewController == nil)
     self.someViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"....

   //Now present self.someViewController..
```

Do this for the view controllers that you use for the tabs.

Comment: This is from my main view.. this is the method i use to view the new view. after I leave the new view, the data is reset (my uiwebview is reest, everything is loaded like its the 1st time...